# How to use autorest generated client with react?

Tags: reactjs, swagger, autorest

We have created an API using .Net core and have created a swagger.json file for all the endpoints. Now I need to integrate the endpoints with my frontend (I am using reactjs for frontend).

I have generated the client via autorest (npmjs.com/package/autorest). Now I want to work with generated client in react. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you give more detailed information about your problem? Can you also add the works you have done so far?

Comment: @E.Zeytinci I cant share the code because of company policy! But i can brief more! We have created API with .NET CORE and create swagger.json file for all the endpoints! Now my task is to integrate endpoints with frontend(I am using reactjs for frontend). I have generated the client via autorest (https://www.npmjs.com/package/autorest). Now i want to work with generated client in react!